# Error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0 but :0.0 works

Tags: cygwin

I can't seem to find what config is missing. It use to work this way there might be something change in cygwin. I had similar setup which was always working. I have make sure that firewall on windows is turn off.

```
 [raza@mytest]$  export DISPLAY=:0.0
 [raza@mytest]$  xhost +
 access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
 [raza@mytest]$  export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
 [raza@mytest]$  xhost +
 xhost:  unable to open display "localhost:0.0"

 [raza@mytest]$   xauth list
 mytest/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7ab7e0be4cf96102784fb9c3bb9f0d3b
 mytest:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7ab7e0be4cf96102784fb9c3bb9f0d3b
 mytest:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7ab7e0be4cf96102784fb9c3bb9f0d3b

 [raza@mytest]$   telnet localhost 6000
 Trying 127.0.0.1...
 telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on
https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-10/msg00111.html

'-nolisten tcp' is now the default, so the server only accepts local connections on a unix domain socket. A '-listen' option has been added which can be used to restore the previous behaviour.

This is how you can void "-nolisten tcp" option and run [xserver automatically](http://www.trueblade.com/knowledge/automatically-starting-a-cygwin-x-server):

```
        <path-to-cygwin>\bin\run.exe -p /usr/X11R6/bin XWin -listen tcp -multiwindow -clipboard -silent-dup-error
```

Comment: `/usr/X11R6/bin` is obsolete. Use `/usr/bin` instead